# Apache 2/mod_rewrite: setting a cookie, then testing for its presence and redirecting to a target when cookie not present

Tags: mod-rewrite, cookies, apache2

I am trying to get this working, using only Apache 2 directives and mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule .* - [CO=setcookietest:1:example.com:60:/] [C]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*setcookietest.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /cookies.html [NC,L]
```

This is not working, it results in an internal server error when hitting that last directive.

Basically, all I want to do is rewrite to a particular page if the server cannot set a test cookie, its value is irrelevant.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite flags are used inside `[` and `]` (a single pair of closing and opening square brackets ). The reason why your server returned a 500 error response is  because you are using double flag delimiters `[.....][...]` in your first rule .

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule .* - [CO=setcookietest:1:example.com:60:/,C]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*setcookietest.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /cookies.html [NC,L]
```